# How to continuously check if the Date has passed in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension and I am letting the user choose a Time when they are usually turning the PC off.
If this time has passed, I want a value to be reset back to 0 and a new Date be created.

## What I did

I created a function that takes a parament of a Dare ISO String, which will then be converted into a Date Object. Inside that function I am comparing between now and the end time, and if the end time is smaller or equal to now, it means the time has passed and the value should be reset. But it's not doing anything.
I call the function inside my `storage.sync.get` method and inside my `storage.onChanged` method, so I always have the correct time to work with. But that does not seem to do it.
Here's the code:
**Background.js**

```js
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes, namespace) => {
  if ("reset" in changes) {
    const reset = changes.reset.newValue;
    console.log(reset);
    checkResetTimer(reset);
  }
});

chrome.storage.sync.get(["reset", "amount"], (obj) => {
  const reset = obj.reset;
  console.log(reset);
  checkResetTimer(reset);
});

function checkResetTimer(isoTime) {
  const resetDate = new Date(isoTime);
  const now = new Date();
  if (resetDate <= now) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ drank: 0 }, () => {
      console.log("drank has been set.");
    });
  }
}
```

The time value I get from the popup, it's an input.

I am at a loss right now. I don't know how to properly have a reset timer.
You can view my whole code in this Repository: https://github.com/Braweria/TakeAGulp

I feel the problem is, that it checks only once, but it needs to check the time consistently.

Answer (score 1):

A crude approach to the problem can be the following:

Background.js

```js
// rest of your code
const resetInterval = setInterval(() => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["reset", "amount"], (obj) => {
        const reset = obj.reset;
        const resetTime = new Date(reset);
        const now = new Date();
        if(resetTime < now) {
            // past your reset time; reset the value here
            
           // maybe clear the interval too to stop the checking
           clearInterval(resetInterval);
        }
   });
}, 1000 * 60); // check every minute
```

Essentially you have to check the value of the reset timer at a given interval to make sure whether that timer has expired.

Comment: That is a crude way. Is it possible to have the interval be exactly on the minute? like on 10:35:00 and not 10:35:23.

Comment: I don't think that's doable using built-in functions. You will need to implement some sort of loop to control the time. Time argument for `setInterval` is basically an indicator that the code will run after one minute; not at the end of the current minute.